# Examples for Execution model(section 4.2.4. Interaction with dynamic features)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know whether it's appropriate to ask this kind of question here. But I have to try it first.

On python3.x doc `Execution model` section [4.2.4. Interaction with dynamic features](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#interaction-with-dynamic-features) says:

> There are several cases where Python statements are illegal when used in conjunction with nested scopes that contain free variables.

I wander what are the `several cases`. Could anyone show some code example for me?

Comment: [PEP 227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) lists (some of) the restrictions: `import *`, bare exec/eval, local variable that shadows a global variable.